# How do I get the parameters inputted by a form on a view component redirected to another page?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I have a form that's rendered as a view component and I need the parameters that's been inputted by the form to be redirected to another page and used there.

Here's what I currently have:

```
@model UserModel
<form asp-controller="Next" asp-action="goToNext" method="post">
<div>
<label asp-for="Params.People">People</label>
<select asp-for="Params.People" asp-items="Model.People" multiple></select>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Preview"/>
</form>
```

I have tried making a controller such as

```
public class NextController : Controller
    {
        //POST
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult goToNext(Parameters parameters)
        {
            return Redirect("PreviewSelection");
        }
    }
```

This is the preview page.

```
@page
@model PreviewModel
<h3>The following information about these users will be downloaded</h3>
<strong>Users</strong>:@Model.PreviewModel.People
```

On the preview page, I would like to show the selected users. How would I go about passing that information to the model of the preview page? Currently, my preview page shows every user instead of the selected users?

Comment: What's stopping you from going directly to the preview page using the form?

Comment: The form is populated by querying a database and getting the information on the people in the database. View Components can't handle HTTPS requests and I need a post request on the preview page because I want to be able to download information about specific users.So I need to take the information from the form and post it to the preview page model.

Comment: @Kaxemer not sure what you mean with "View Models cannot handle HTTPS requests.". Can you elaborate? Also, please include the controller/method for `PreviewSelection`.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.0) 

 _A view component never directly handles a request. Typically, a view component initializes a model and passes it to a view by calling the View method_

I'm reusing this page, so using a view component seemed like a solid choice.

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` returns a 302 response to the browser, which will then perform a HTTP GET request to the specified endpoint.

You will need to write a controller method to handle the subsequent GET request.

Rather than calling `Redirect`, call `RedirectToAction`, where you can pass `parameters` as the second argument, then this will be converted into a query string that can be parsed by your controller e.g.

```
return RedirectToAction("PreviewSelection", parameters);
```

Then:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PreviewSelection(Parameters parameters)
{
    // do something with parameters
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but apparently the Redirect method can't be overloaded for two parameters and only takes one parameter. Is there another method I can use?

Comment: Ah yes, you want RedirectToAction rather than Redirect. I'll update my answer.